Flutter nfc_manager not works in ios
I have implemented nfc reading in an Flutter project with nfc_manager . Android works fine, but the iOS does not detect any thing and afetr some time it got timeout error.
I have done the 3 steps for iOS based on the documentation.

Add Near Field Communication Tag Reader Session Formats Entitlements to your entitlements.

Add NFCReaderUsageDescription to your Info.plist.

Add com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes and com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers to your Info.plist as needed.


Im sure about 1st and 2nd step, but Im not sure to implement step 3 in a correct way.
What should I set to these two variables



Please help me to fill the varable with the correct values.

Please check, I am not sure really, but i do. not think third step is ncessary, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app

@Shivbaba'sson Thanks for answering. I'll read it. Do you have information about NFC tags? Is there any special tag type working with iPhone? or all kinds of them work?

I have not implemented NFC tag yet, NFC should work with fine with iPhone.

What I understand is that there are several types of NFC tags. One is NTAG(213/215/216) that iPhone works with.
I have several types of tags but the iPhone works with the NTAG series.
Android works with most of them.
